# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect - Windows 10

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, tomcat7, windows-10

I am running tomcat 7.0.52 in my windows 10 64 bit machine. I have set jdk 1.7 in my java home path. While i running my tomcat with application build I am getting java.net.SocketException. How to fix this issue?

```
IAM_INFO_STATEMENT - Going to initialize IAMProxy instance



"" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" ""-"" ""-"" """" ""ROOT"" """" " "" "-#APPLICATION#-"

"""Site24x7"" ""192.168.220.116"" ""vijay-2754"" ""-1"" ""2"" """" ""72"" ""com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy"" ""init"" ""WARNING"" ""14-02-2017 04:04:10:003"" """" ""java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.executeRemoteMethod(IAMProxy.java:894)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.invokeAPI(IAMProxy.java:733)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy$ProxyHandler.invoke(IAMProxy.java:108)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getSystemConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.init(IAMProxy.java:240)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.<init>(IAMProxy.java:210)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getInstance(IAMProxy.java:285)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getProperty(IAMProxy.java:293)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMConfiguration.getConfig(IAMConfiguration.java:12)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMUtil.getPartnerAccount(IAMUtil.java:1598)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getCurrentPartnerAccount(IAMProxy.java:1343)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getPartnerURL(IAMProxy.java:1323)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getIAMServerURL(IAMProxy.java:989)
    at org.apache.jsp.migrate_jsp._jspService(migrate_jsp.java:64)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.SubuserFilter.doFilter(SubuserFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.UriFilter.doFilter(UriFilter.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.AccountFilter.doFilter(AccountFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.CnameFilter.doFilter(CnameFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.sas.audit.AuditFilter.doFilter(AuditFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.sas.security.filter.SASFilter.doFilter(SASFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.S247IAMFilter.doFilter(S247IAMFilter.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.filter.URLRedirectFilter.doFilter(URLRedirectFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.PersistenceFilter.doFilter(PersistenceFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.mi.util.MIFeatureTrackingFilter.doFilter(MIFeatureTrackingFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.iam.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.zoho.logs.logclient.filter.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.zoho.instrument.InstrumentFilter.doFilter(InstrumentFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.executeRemoteMethod(IAMProxy.java:858)
    ... 78 more
"" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" ""-"" ""-"" """" ""ROOT"" """" " "" "-#APPLICATION#-"

"""Site24x7"" ""192.168.220.116"" ""vijay-2754"" ""-1"" ""2"" """" ""72"" ""com.adventnet.iam.IAMUtil"" ""getPartnerAccount"" ""WARNING"" ""14-02-2017 04:04:10:005"" """" ""java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.executeRemoteMethod(IAMProxy.java:894)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.invokeAPI(IAMProxy.java:733)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy$ProxyHandler.invoke(IAMProxy.java:108)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getSystemConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.init(IAMProxy.java:240)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.<init>(IAMProxy.java:210)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getInstance(IAMProxy.java:285)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getProperty(IAMProxy.java:293)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMConfiguration.getConfig(IAMConfiguration.java:12)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMUtil.getPartnerAccount(IAMUtil.java:1598)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getCurrentPartnerAccount(IAMProxy.java:1343)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getPartnerURL(IAMProxy.java:1323)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.getIAMServerURL(IAMProxy.java:989)
    at org.apache.jsp.migrate_jsp._jspService(migrate_jsp.java:64)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.SubuserFilter.doFilter(SubuserFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.UriFilter.doFilter(UriFilter.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.AccountFilter.doFilter(AccountFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.CnameFilter.doFilter(CnameFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.sas.audit.AuditFilter.doFilter(AuditFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.sas.security.filter.SASFilter.doFilter(SASFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.S247IAMFilter.doFilter(S247IAMFilter.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.filter.URLRedirectFilter.doFilter(URLRedirectFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.PersistenceFilter.doFilter(PersistenceFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.mi.util.MIFeatureTrackingFilter.doFilter(MIFeatureTrackingFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.iam.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.zoho.logs.logclient.filter.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.zoho.instrument.InstrumentFilter.doFilter(InstrumentFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.adventnet.iam.IAMProxy.executeRemoteMethod(IAMProxy.java:858)
    ... 78 more
"" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" ""-"" ""-"" """" ""ROOT"" """" " "" "-#APPLICATION#-"

"""Site24x7"" ""192.168.220.116"" ""vijay-2754"" ""-1"" ""3"" """" ""66"" ""com.adventnet.iam.security.IAMSecurityException"" ""<init>"" ""INFO"" ""14-02-2017 04:04:10:064"" ""IAMSecurityException ErrorCode: This request is not passed via SecurityFilter"" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" ""-"" ""-"" """" ""ROOT"" """" " "" "-#APPLICATION#-"

"""Site24x7"" ""192.168.220.116"" ""vijay-2754"" ""-1"" ""3"" """" ""66"" ""com.adventnet.webmon.util.LoggerUtil"" ""log"" ""INFO"" ""14-02-2017 04:04:10:064"" ""Unable to Set the App Account in the Cookie msp_zaaid"" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" ""-"" ""-"" """" ""ROOT"" """" " "" "-#APPLICATION#-"

"""Site24x7"" ""192.168.220.116"" ""vijay-2754"" ""-1"" ""4"" """" ""70"" ""com.adventnet.iam.security.IAMSecurityException"" ""<init>"" ""INFO"" ""14-02-2017 04:04:21:592"" ""IAMSecurityException ErrorCode: This request is not passed via SecurityFilter"" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" ""-"" ""-"" """" ""ROOT"" """" " "" "-#APPLICATION#-"

"""Site24x7"" ""192.168.220.116"" ""vijay-2754"" ""-1"" ""4"" """" ""70"" ""com.adventnet.iam.security.IAMSecurityException"" ""<init>"" ""INFO"" ""14-02-2017 04:04:21:592"" ""IAMSecurityException ErrorCode: This request is not passed via SecurityFilter"" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" """" ""-"" ""-"" """" ""ROOT"" """" " "" "-#APPLICATION#-"

"""Site24x7"" ""192.168.220.116"" ""vijay-2754"" ""-1"" ""4"" """" ""70"" ""com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.PersistenceFilter"" ""doFilter"" ""SEVERE"" ""14-02-2017 04:04:21:593"" ""Exception throwncom.adventnet.iam.security.IAMSecurityException: This request is not passed via SecurityFilter
    at com.adventnet.iam.security.SecurityRequestWrapper.getInstance(SecurityRequestWrapper.java:692)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.servlets.PersistenceFilter.doFilter(PersistenceFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.webmon.mi.util.MIFeatureTrackingFilter.doFilter(MIFeatureTrackingFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.adventnet.iam.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.zoho.logs.logclient.filter.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.zoho.instrument.InstrumentFilter.doFilter(InstrumentFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I referred something google and find to add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in java_opts. I tried this one too. But still the issue persists? Any idea on this?
thanks for any help.

Comment: do you run the tomcat on a privileged port? (<1024) Do you run the tomcat with admin privileges?

Comment: You have a local firewall rule that is disallowing connections to whatever port it is. Remove it, or amend it to allow connections from the localhost.

Comment: i ran tomcat on 8443.how to check whether it is admin privileged? @thst

Comment: @EJP how to modify the firewall rule ? & where to modify? & what to modify?

Comment: firewall was blocked while allowing java process